# Question about propellers

Tags: fluid-dynamics

A ship moves forwards because a rotating propeller sends water backwards. The diameter of the propeller is as large as possible because in order to be efficient it must push the the greatest feasible amount of water with the lowest acceleration. Could someone explain me the reason for this?

Comment: Also this question shows you are about to ask your self through to the solution of turbulence. The answer here doesn't make the point. If you remain on low reynolds number, you would be able to do it with almost no losses. the video at 27:00 -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=51-6QCJTAjU&index=7&list=PL0EC6527BE871ABA3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thrust is the mass of water moved per second times the velocity of motion (of the water).
Energy is the mass of water moved times the velocity squared (over two).
So to minimize energy for a given thrust, you want to minimize velocity (and maximize mass). (There's also the issue of cavitation, which you want to avoid by keeping the pressure low.)

The same principle applies in aircraft.

Comment: @veronica - It's why large helicopters have big, slow blades, rather than the small, high-speed props used by quadcopters.